# How to know if upsert was successful and if I can get _id of updated/new inserted document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using this code to make upsert functiona to mongo server via mongoose

```
update({'name' : 'Jaki'}, {'name' : 'Charley', 'gender' : 'f'}, {upsert: true})
```

and it works, but how to know if operation was successful and if I can get `_id` of updated/new inserted document?
(In sqlalchemy after session flush() I can get id of orm updated/inserted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) to get the modified records. Do not forget `upsert:true`.